# Laravel select from 2 tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've searched a lot and can't find a solution. I have 3 tables, one shopping_carts table, one product and finally an items table. I have created an eshop and I want to display the quantity of each product after a user clicks the add to cart button. My code is below but that returns only the product that exists in items table and it's logic. I need the quantity of that product in items table but I need also the rest products from the products table.

```
 return $query = Product::select('title','price','imageUrl','quantity','products.id')
           ->join('items','items.product_id','=','products.id')
           ->where('shopping_cart_id', '=' ,$id)->get();
```

**shopping_carts**
[image]

**products**
[image]

**items**
[image]

Comment: Are you not using relationships?

Comment: change `join` to `leftJoin` and check the results.

Comment: as i found, you want to have products that dont have any item , but your query just get products that have at least one item in otems table, so you need to use leftjoin instead of join

Comment: i want the products that have items because i need the quantity column but i need also the rest of products because i have to show in my page all the products.Some may have quantity but others not..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways:-

First one is by using relationships from here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

The second one is by modifying your existing query:-

```
return $query = Product::select('title','price','imageUrl','quantity','products.id')
       ->leftJoin('items','items.product_id','=','products.id')
       ->where('shopping_cart_id', '=' ,$id)->get();
```

Comment: leftJoin gives the same result

Comment: My relationships are ready and working..Items are connected with products with one to many and the reverse but i can't get the result i want..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$products = DB::table('items')
    ->join('products', 'items.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->where('shopping_cart_id', '=' , $id)
    ->get();
```

Or Using relationships

```
class ShoppingCart extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
    }
}

class Item extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

then use

```
$shopping_cart = ShoppingCart::with(['items', 'items.product'])->find($id);
```

Updated answer with all product

```
Product::select('products.id', 'products.title', 'products.price', 'products.imageUrl', 
                 DB:raw('(CASE WHEN items.qunatity IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE items.qunatity END) as quantity')
       ->leftJoin('items', function($join) use($id){
            $join->on('products.id', '=', 'items.product_id')
                ->on('items.shopping_cart_id', '=', $id);
        })->get();
```

Comment: Which one returns undefined?

Comment: I forgot to subscribe in my angular app..I fixed it and your solution gives me again the two items and not all of them..I want baguette and Banana as it returns right with their quantities but i want also the cherries which i don't get

Comment: There is only two items in your shopping cart items table. right?

Comment: Yes!! I want these 2 with their quantities and i want also the remaining products from products table which are cherries..Union worked somehow but not with right results..It returned me again the items in items table..

Comment: Imagine an e-shop where i keep a shopping_cart_id for each user and when this user enters the site i must show him all the products and if he had clicked some of them i want to show the quantity..So obviously some of them will have quantity and other not..

Comment: So you want all products with quantities of added products. if not added quantity expects 0. right?

Comment: yes..If the product does not exist in items table i want to return it with zero quantity

Comment: I have added one more query to my answer. Please check.

Comment: syntax error first or second line something is wrong

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer with some changes to noufalcep code

```
return Product::select('products.id', 'products.title', 'products.price', 'products.imageUrl',
           DB::raw('CASE WHEN items.quantity IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE items.quantity END as quantity'))
       ->leftJoin('items', function($join) use($id){
           $join->on('products.id', '=', 'items.product_id')
               ->where('items.shopping_cart_id', '=', $id);
       })->get();
```